# \blx @keyaliases@1 entry could not be found in the database

Tags: biblatex, microtype

The compilation of the following MCE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titleps}
% \usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newpagestyle{mainmatter}[]{%
  \sethead{\citeauthor{knuth:ct:a}}{}{}
}

\pagestyle{mainmatter}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newrefsection
\section{Foo}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

leads to the following warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                issue
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

though rerunning `biber` doesn't change anything. An additional warning appears as soon as `microtype` is loaded:

```
Package biblatex Warning: The following entry could not be found
(biblatex)                in the database:
(biblatex)                \blx @keyaliases@1 
(biblatex)                Please verify the spelling and rerun
(biblatex)                LaTeX afterwards.
```

which disappears as soon as either `\tableofcontents` or `\newrefsection` or `\section{Foo}` is dropped.

Do you understand what's going on?

Comment: I cannot offer an explanation for now, but loading `microtype` with the option `nopatch=toc` would at least get rid of the second warning. The Rerun warning will stay though (also without `microtype`).

Comment: As I wrote in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/544, there is a chance this issue no longer appears in `biblatex` 3.17 whose release is imminent.

Comment: @Robert Indeed, good catch!

Comment: @moewe I confirm this issue no longer appears  with `biblatex` 3.17 (and `biber` 2.17).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MWE compiles fine with `biblatex` 3.17 and Biber 2.17.

I did not investigate the matter too closely, but most likely the fix was included in commits to address https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1196 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1144.